# How to remove DownActionBar from devices without hardware menu button?

Tags: android, android-actionbaractivity

I use ActionBarActivity, but my appliction is need not this downBar.

[link: Screenshot](http://img.tatfisher.ru/?v=screenttt.png)

How to remove it?

```
public class myActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
                    //...
        }

}
```

I need to use ActionBarActivity in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:uiOptions` from your `<application>` or `<activity>` elements in the manifest, where you are presently requesting the split action bar.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution did not help me.

Comment: @Vladislav: Also, remove the `android.support.UI_OPTIONS` `<meta-data>` elements, wherever they may appear in your manifest. You can read more about the split action bar in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).